# Passing Timer to a WeakReference

Tags: android, performance, timer

I am not an expert in `WeakReferences`, as I am getting acquainted by them just now along the way.

I am using `Timer` with `TimerTask` in my activity.
It is known that Timers can not be reused whenever you have called `cancel()` on them, until you create a new instance of it.

So what I am doing is to create a `Timer` globally in my activity.

`Timer timer;`

and inside my onResume(), I instantiate it by `timer = new Timer();`

The reason for this is to avoid the `Timer already cancelled` exception. Because the onPause() might be called when the mobile gets screenlock or whatever, and I am calling `timer.cancel()` in my `onPause()` method.

My question is, when the timer was cancelled, does it automatically becomes prone for `Garbage collection` as it is totally pointless to use it again AFAIK. If this is the case, how fast does it get collected ?

Is using a `WeakReference` here comes in handy ? if not, where does it help to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of eligibility of Timer to be GC'ed you will not benefit from keeping a `WeakReference` to `Timer` instance, because, as you said, it can not be reused anymore after `cancel()`.

`WeakReference` is useful to keep track of object that you **can** use, but do not want to keep that object in RAM if no one else uses it (i.e. no one keeps [hard] references to it). Then it will be GC'ed and your `WeakReference` also becomes useless. (and you do not prevent GC of the object by keeping only `WeekReference` to it).

Well, hope it is not too vague.

I personally use `WeakReferences` to have rough idea of possible memory leaks in junit tests.

I could give you another example of usage - instead of having custom inner `Handler` class defined in `Activity` class, which has implicit reference to your `Activity` and could create potential memory leaks, you could define custom `Handler class` as static nested class and keep `WeakReference` to your `Activity` instance as a private member, so you can continue calling your `Activity` methods from inside custom `Handler` class.